# Running PFPGrowth algorithm in Mahout from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, mahout

I want to run PFPGrowth algorithm in Mahout examples from Eclipse. when I import mahout in eclipse it shows following errors in import Maven Projects window:

> mahout-collection-codegen-plugin:1.0:generate (1 errors)
>
> maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run  (1 errors)

what should I do?

Comment: search the maven repo for the dependencies and add them to your pom.xml

Comment: I am new in maven would you pls tell me where must i search the maven repo?

Answer (score 0):

Search the maven repo for the dependencies and add them to your pom.xml.

Take a look a [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) to understand how maven work.

You'll also need to learn and understand Maven's [dependencies mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

The Maven Repo for Apache Mahout is [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.mahout).